# Keyup and Change function transfer and remove text

Tags: jquery

Let me preface this with: I am very new to the coding side of things, I come from a design background... but here we go...

I am using the keyup and change jquery to transfer values over to a display image that will be printed (The values are also inserted into the DB).

My problem is the options for my input include both the size and description, but all I want to transfer with keyup/change is the size.

```
    Cake Type: <select name="Cake" id="cake">
    <option value="5 3/8&#34; Cake Pie" >5 3/8" - Cake Pie</option>
    <option value="5 7/8&#34; Pretzal Pie" >5 7/8" - Pretzal Pie</option>
    <option value="5 1/2&#34; Wing Ding" >5 1/2" - Wing Ding</option>
    <option value="5 1/2&#34; Objectonator" >5 1/2" - Objectonator</option>
    </select>
```

Currently I use this the keyup and change jquery to transfer the value:

```
$("#cake").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#cake_transfer").text(value);
}).keyup();
$("#cake").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#cake_transfer").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

So is it possible to remove the description and just transfer the size (ie: 5 1/2")?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would imagine that calling `keyup()` after processing the `keyup` event might create a never ending loop .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#cake").on('change keyup', function() {
    var value = $('option:selected', this).text();
    $("#cake_transfer").text(value.split('-')[0]);
}).keyup();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/8ELQM/4/)**

Comment: Actually! this just grabs the first 6 characters, so it doesn't work for sizes with more that 6 characters

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$("#cake").on('change keyup', function () {
    var value = $(this).val().split(' ');  // split into words
    var size = value[0] + " " + value[1];  // first 2 words
    $("#cake_transfer").text(size);
});​
```

Im using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so that you can combine the 2 events (`keyup` and `change`) and splitting the value into words - just getting the 2 words - the problem with this is that its rather fixed ... if you could separate the size and description with a `-` or `%` it would be a lot easier

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/rLRFx/)

Comment: Ah I had hastily accepted the above answer - But I now realize that it was just grabbing the first six characters, and that is problematic because there are some sizes with more characters than that.

Comment: I am trying to use your code, but it seems to be breaking my other jquery functions, and then nothing works.

Comment: how is it "breaking" the other code ? any errors ? the above code replaces your 2 functions in your question ... what version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: I am not sure what was happening, I think it was my cache. But I got it working with the code from the above post using the serperate dash that you mentioned. Thanks for the help!